# what if i use html 5 for one webpage when total project created in html4?

Tags: html, user-interface, web

I built my website in html4 and would like to add new tab(which is a link opens in new window). Would like to include videos in it and want to make this page in html5. can i make like this? What are the constraints?

Sorry for bad english and need help.

Answer (score 1):

yes, since you want it opened on a new window, then it should be on a new page.

the constraints are that your html5 page should have this at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and your html4 page should have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

More info on the declarations [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any constraints. The client-side browser is what will handle all of it, and HTML5 is just the term used to refer to features that modern browsers support.  The only thing you might want to consider is writing it in a way where it will be backwards compatible with older clients since the rest of your site was written to support HTML4.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Change the top line of your html file into

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And then you can add html5 tags in your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use html5 for only one page.  You need to change only html declaration on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You should remember that doctype declaration must be the very first thing on your page and you can't override it

Answer (score 0):

There are **no constraints**..In fact **you could change all your pages to HTML5** and your HTML 4 code will still work the same as before. No need to change anything as html 5 is fully backward compatible,i.e. html 4 elements work fine in it.